# How do I reset Highcharts bar color back to it's original color?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, colors

I have Highcharts version 4.1.10

I have a bar chart where I change the color of the bar when a value exceeds a threshold.

```js
//timeout calls this at regular interval
function myTimeoutFunction() {
    var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: applicationPath + 'myWebapi/valuesToMeasure',
        cache: false,
        success: myFunctionOnSuccess,
        error: myFunctionOnError
    });
}

function myFunctionOnSuccess(myData) {
    if (myData.value > 500000000) {
        mySeriesDataArray.data.push({ y: myData.value, color: "rgb(255, 0, 0)" });
    } 
    else  {
        mySeriesDataArray.data.push({ y: myData.value);
    }

    //...

    mySeries.setData(mySeriesDataArray.data,true);
}
```

The series data is updated on an interval using a timeout.

When a value exceeds the threshold it works as expected and colors the bar red.

But when the value goes back below the threshold the bar stays red.  I assume the color style just gets held onto.

Is there a way to tell Highcharts to reset the color to the original color that Highcharts automatically picked for the series in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the solution below?

```
mySeriesDataArray.data.push({ y: myData.value, color: null });
```

I mean, simply remove `color` property.

If this won't help, you can always use:

```
mySeriesDataArray.data.push({ y: myData.value, color: mySeries.color }); // re-apply color
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to have to go find the series color if I could help it.  It's odd, I could have sworn I tried null like that before and it didn't work, but I tried again and it is indeed working, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting the color counter before updating.

```
chart.colorCounter = 0;
```

Here's an example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/Lekuesqf/)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work.  Also, that property is not documented on the Highcharts site as far as I can tell.

Comment: Try the updated code. Replace #container with the proper name

Comment: I didn't use your code literally like that, I used my chart variable.  It gives an error message since counters doesn't exist.  Can you make a functioning fiddle example?

Comment: I've updated the answer and posted the link to a working example